# Choose when files gets unpacked when installing .deb file

Tags: debian, deb, dpkg

I am creating a Debian package, I have 3 main directories called /backup /usr and /var. I want to unpack the /backup folder and do somethings with the content inside then after unpack the rest (/usr and /var). I have a few text files in the backup folder with information of files that I need to backup in the /usr and /var directories before the Debian package unpack and overwrites the files in said directories.

Comment: Not sure I understand. "Unpacking" phase is to override files (from .deb). BTW `/backup` is an horrible choice of directory [use /var/lib/yourpackage/backup). I think you should either uses .deb in standard way, or you should study much more how it works. In this case, I think you want a `preinst` script to backup the files. Creation of directory is usually done earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regardless of where the backup dir is sitting, the issue I am facing is that the preinst fires of before the directories are copied over. I need the backup folder to be present with its content before the preinst. After that the rest of the directories should be created/installed with its content

Comment: You need the content of backup? Or just create the correct directories? What about not installing things in /usr, but just in your /var/lib and then postisnt will override the files when, as you want [but I find it ugly, because now you do not have trace of which files belong to which package]. I'm difficulty to understand what you are doing [so reframing]. Instead of backups, you should have the original packages, to restore files [usual way]

Comment: Let me explain, we develop our own inhouse software. The software is installed in /usr/local/x/y/z and in /var/www/html/x/y/z. I run pipelines on our git server to compile the new/modified files. We then create a debian package with those files to patch/update to new versions. We read the files that have been updaed and modified in the pipeline and write it to text file. That text file is in the backup dir of the package. I want to read that text file in order to backup the old files before replacing with the new ones. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: For the executable I see some problem: how the user select which patch to install? And the first installation? You should force main program before patches. For binary part, I would just distribute a package with all binaries (we [Debian] change version of a package, just when we change maintainer (so just a metadata). Disk, network is cheap. [/usr/local is for sys administrators (local changes). /opt may be better for external packages]. For html I do not know, but the first point (how to update, select) make me to thing. But maybe a .deb is not the best way for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to reimplement what a repository and dpkg are supposed to be doing.

If the files are already in git, what's the point of making backups of those? You could just keep all generated .debs ever made, and you'd automatically have backups for every "snapshot".

If for some reason you are dropping those packages, and still want to generate backups, I think it might be simpler to just try to hook `dpkg-repack` from a `dpkg`invoke hook, so that you can generate .debs out of the installed files before installing the new versions. If that does not work either because there are too many files that would bloat the .deb, I guess another option would be to inject the list directly into the preinst script, instead of keeping it in the filsystem, which as you say will not be available at the time the maintscript is executed. But TBH, all these seem to be using the wrong tools for the job.